# about pod installation error in ios project

Tags: ios, cocoapods

when i am trying to install the pod its showing errors. how to solve this?

> Apples-MacBook-Pro:~ apple$ cd /Users/apple/Desktop/lkmmlkmk 
>   Apples-MacBook-Pro:lkmmlkmk apple$ pod init [!] Existing Podfile found
>   in directory Apples-MacBook-Pro:lkmmlkmk apple$ pod install Setting up
>   CocoaPods master repo fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown
>   revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths
>   from revisions, like this: 'git  [...] --
>   [...]' fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or
>   path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from
>   revisions, like this: 'git  [...] -- [...]'
>   fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the
>   working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>   'git  [...] -- [...]'   $ /usr/bin/git -C
>   /Users/apple/.cocoapods/repos/master fetch origin --progress   fatal:
>   'origin' does not appear to be a git repository   fatal: Could not
>   read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights   and the
>   repository exists. [!] Unable to add a source with url
>   `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`. You can try
>   adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

Comment: Pod file is already present, why are you using pod init?

Comment: if i am not adding also its showing same error

Comment: Use pod install

Answer (score 1):

This problem got solve by re setting the git manually if anyone having same issue just reset the cocoa-pods it will help you.
Go to ~/.cocoapods/repos and run git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
it will help you to resolve the solution